# Let $A$ and $B$ be two square Hermitian matrices such that $AB = 0 = BA$. Prove that $\mbox{rank} (A + B) = \mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank} (B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two square Hermitian matrices such that $AB = 0 = BA$. Prove that $\mbox{rank} (A + B) = \mbox{rank}(A) + \mbox{rank} (B)$.

This is what I have so far. It is clear that rank($A + B$) $\leq$ rank($A$) + rank($B$). So, it only suffices to show that rank($A + B$) $\geq$ rank($A$) + rank($B$).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this true? $B=-A$ gives $A+B=0$ so rank zero, but then I think $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a contradiction... am I missing something obvious?

Comment: $AB = BA = 0$ does not imply that $A = - B$.

Comment: Of course not; I don't see why that's relevant. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: The title is misleading. $AB = 0 = BA$ is a much stronger assumption than  that they commute. And moreover, @EricStucky is correct, this statement is false by his counterexample.

Comment: I do understand your point now @EricStucky. In addition to the original assumption, assume that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable.  So you can assume they are diagonal.  Then the rank is just the number of nonzero eigenvalues...

Answer (score 1):

**Claim 1:** $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalized.

By the Schur Unitary Theorem for commuting matrices, we have that there exists $U$ unitary such that 
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
U^* A U = T_A \quad \text{and} \quad U^* B U = T_B
\end{equation}
where $T_A$ and $T_B$ are upper triangular matrix not necessarily equal to each other. Since $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and using \eqref{1}, we have
$$T_A^* = T_A \quad \text{and} \quad T_B^* = T_B$$
The above implies that $T_A$ and $T_B$ are diagonal matrices. Thus, $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalized. Thus, by **Claim 1**, we know that $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalized. That is
$$A = UD_AU^* \quad \text{and} \quad B = UD_BU^*$$
where $U$ is unitary and $D_A$ and $D_B$ are diagonal matrices containing the non-zeros eigenvalues of $A$ and 
$B$, respectively. Thus 
$$A + B = UD_AU^* + UD_BU^* \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{rank}(A+B) = \text{rank }A + \text{rank }B$$